# Filenamefilter Necesito que me avise cuando no encuentre nada

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
public class filtrado {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

try{
        File f = new File("."); // current directory
        FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
                return lowercaseName.startsWith("g");                   
            }
        };
            File[] files = f.listFiles(textFilter);
        for (File file : files) {                 
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.print("directory:");
            } else {
                System.out.print("     file:");
            }
            System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
                }

                }catch (Exception e) { 
                }

    }

}
```

Básicamente el funcionamiento es el siguiente:
Me busca en mi directorio cualquier archivo que se empiece por "g". Y lo clasifica en si es directorio o fichero.

Pero necesito algo más que no sé como hacer. Necesito cuando no encuentre ningun archivo que me avise por ejemplo: No existe ningun Fichero/Directorio que empiece con G.

Como lo hago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de la siguiente manera, lo probé y funciona como lo solicitas.

```
try {
        File f = new File("."); // current directory

        FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                String lowercaseName = name.toLowerCase();
                return lowercaseName.startsWith("g");
            }
        };

        File[] files = f.listFiles(textFilter);
        if (files.length > 0) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.print("directory:");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("     file:");
                }
                System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        } else{
            System.out.println("No existe ningun Fichero/Directorio que empiece con G");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Comment: no sabes las de horas que he estado.. y sabía que era una tontería pero nada de nada... 

Mil gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes contar cuantas veces tu bucle encuentra Archivos/Directorios que coincidan con la letra G, En caso contrario pones el mensaje que desees

Comment: No te entiendo.. No sé para que quieres que cuente los archivos... ni la ultilidad de ello.. lo siento.. T_T

Comment: si los cuentas podras saber si hay alguna cantidad de archivos con esa letra inicial, si el contador nunca conto nada es por que no existen

Comment: el conteo sería algo así:         File[] ficheros = f.listFiles();
for (int x=0;x<ficheros.length;x++){


El problema es que no sé donde introducirlo

Comment: y que haces con el metodo accept.

Comment: Es que he probado con accept hacer cosas pero nada.. Estoy bastante perdida con el tema filtros y el programa me va perfecto menos por el echo de que cuando no encuentra nada no dice nada..

Comment: Intenta extrayendoles el nombre a los ficheros/directorios `if(file.getName().starWith("g")){ 
    //tuContador
}`

Comment: Supongo que pensamos diferente o no acabo de entenderte lo siento.. Me tienes bastante perdida con la forma que quieres que lo haga...

Comment: Espera creo que te he pillado estoy toqueteando..

Comment: el problema de tu forma es que donde "g" puede ir cualquier cosa.. T_T

Comment: ya te sirve con la letra G?

Comment: He echo el recuento.. y si lo hace y me cuenta cuantos hay... pero no consigo nada más.. es decir sigo con el mismo problema.. sorry no sé hacerlo.

Comment: Es decir me hace el recuento, pero si no encuentra nada me ignora el programa por completo.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54188/discussion-between-dacoso-and-montse-mkd).

Comment: Sucede lo mismo.. cuando no encuentra nada no da mensaje de error..